# semantic analysis in case of syntax errors detected during syntax analysing

Tags: parsing, compilation

I know that syntax  analysis  is needed to determine if the series of tokens given are appropriate in a language (by parsing these tokens to produce a syntax tree), and detect errors occurred during the parsing of input code, which caused by grammatically incorrect statements.

I also know that semantic analysis is then performed on the syntax tree to produce an annotated tree ,checking  aspects that are not related to the syntactic form( like type correctness of expressions and declaration prior to use) , detecting errors occurred during the execution of the code, after it has been parsed as grammatically correct.

However , the following issue is not clear to me :

**In case of syntax error detected by the syntax analyzer - does it mean that should be no semantic analysis ? Or perhaps the recovery from errors (in syntax analysis) should make the semantic analysis possible to  be carried out?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you compile an incorrect program, you generally want the compiler to inform you about as many problems as possible, so that you can fix them all before attempting to compile the program again. However, you don't want the compiler to report the same error many times, or to report things which are not really errors but rather the result of the compiler getting confused by previous errors.

Or am I projecting my expectations on you? Perhaps I should have written that whole paragraph in first person, since it is really about what I expect from a compiler. Perhaps you have different expectations. Or perhaps your expectations are similar to mine. Whatever they are, you should probably write your compiler to satisfy them. That's basically the point of writing your own compiler.

So, if you share my expectations, you probably want to do as much semantic analysis as you can feel reasonably confident about. You might, for example, be able to do type checking inside some functions, because there are no syntax errors within those functions. On the other hand, that's a lot of work and there's always the chance that the resulting error messages will not be helpful.

That's not very precise, because there really is no definitive answer. But you should at least be able to answer your own question on your own behalf.  If your compiler does a lousy job of error reporting and you find that frustrating when you try to use your compiler, then you should work on making the reports better. (But, of course, time is limited and you might well feel that your compiler will be better if it optimises better, even though the error reports are not so great.)